# Isolation levels and not skipping any data

Tags: mysql, innodb, isolation-level

Say we want to read new events from our MySQL (InnoDB) table `event`. We remember the last (auto-increment) ID we have seen, and query `WHERE id > @LastSeenId`.

**What if IDs 1 through 10 are available, except that ID 4 is yet uncommitted?**

Clearly, it is important that we never skip any rows that may exist. If we were to skip ID 4, we will never see it again, and will have missed it permanently, which must be prevented.

I presume this depends on the isolation level the query runs in.

**1. Do I understand correctly that `Serializable` (and no other level) will provide the required behavior?**

That is, it will wait for commit/rollback of any uncommitted transactions affecting the rows matching the condition (`id > @LastSeenId`)?

**2. More specifically, if we are not using database transactions explicitly, is the outcome determined by the default isolation level - even for a single `SELECT` query?**

For context, we are using the official MySQL connector for .NET.

Comment: Are you creating ID manually?

Comment: No, auto-increment. I will update my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something you can test yourself with the mysql client and two windows.

Open window 1, get into the mysql client, create a table, and fill it with values that will be committed.

```
mysql1> use test;

mysql1> create table event (id serial primary key);

mysql1> insert into event values (1), (2), (3), (5);
```

Now start a transction. Insert value 4, as in your example.

```
mysql1> begin;

mysql1> insert into event values (4);
```

Do not commit the last insert yet.

Open window 2, get into the mysql client, set the transaction isolation for your session, and query for the range of data.

```
mysql2> use test;

mysql2> set tx_isolation = serializable;

mysql2> begin;

mysql2> select * from event where id >= 1;
```

The select hangs at this stage, waiting.

This is because in serializable level, all select queries implicitly try to acquire a shared lock, as if you had added the `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` (or `FOR SHARE` in MySQL 8.0 syntax) clause to the end of the select query. This is a [locking read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html). It's trying to acquire a [gap lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks) on the range of id values, but it can't get that lock yet, because there's an uncommitted row created by window 1, which falls in the range.

Now in window 1, commit the transaction (make sure you do this before window 2 times out after 50 seconds):

```
mysql1> commit;
```

Window 2 immediately returns, and now it sees the full set of data values.

```
mysql2> select * from event where id >= 1;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
+----+
```

Now try to insert a new row in Window 1:

```
mysql1> begin;

mysql1> insert into event values (6);
```

Now *this* window hangs. Why? Because it's trying to lock the row it's inserting, but window 2 still holds a gap lock on the *range* of rows `where id > 1` — which includes the new value 6.

This is how MySQL ensures repeatable read. It uses gap locks to prevent insertion of new rows that would enter into the range it has locked, because a new row would affect the set of rows the current transaction is trying to preserve.

Eventually, window 1 will time out, if window 2 doesn't finish its transaction and release its gap lock:

```
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

All of this has nothing to do with auto-increment. As you saw in my example inserts, I'm overriding the auto-increment anyway. It has only to do with locks on rows and gaps, regardless of how the values in those rows were generated.

I have to comment also that the problem you're trying to solve is essentially a publish/subscribe model, which is more suited to a [message queue technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue), not an RDBMS technology. You should consider using a message queue as a complementary technology to your RDBMS.

Comment: _Very_ thorough. Thank you. The advantage of using the same RDBMS is ACID compliance and being able to insert the event records in the same transaction as other inserts. Are there techniques we can use with message queues that will give us comparable guarantees?

Comment: Save the data to the SQL database, then also post to the message queue a notice that id 4 (or whatever) has been created. Then a client that is looking for records to process doesn't have to poll the database, it just pops an id from the queue and it has assurance that the id exists in the database and that no other client is working on it. They can come in any order, and you don't worry about the locking or anything.

Comment: Yes, but what if the message queue fails (crash, connection interruption, ...)? The data is there, but it was never broadcast. What if we must _guarantee_ consistency between the data and its broadcasts, such as in financial systems?

Comment: The data in the database should have a column indicating whether it has been processed or not. After the worker does its work, it updated the respective flag in the database. This also accounts for cases where the worker crashes, because you can check if an item in the database is marked "in progress" but hasn't been updated in 5+ minutes. Those need to be re-queued. I worked on a system that used this strategy, it made automated phone calls for schools, and we relied on this to make sure we didn't skip any calls, nor accidentally call some parent multiple times.

Comment: Agreed. And if the worker must (A) process each record exactly once, and (B) broadcast events _in order_, then the worker must read items using the Serializable isolation level, correct?

Comment: But serializable would not guarantee events were processed in order. It only guarantees that an insert is blocked while the reader is reading the set of events. That blocked insert might still be an event that should be in the middle of the set.

Comment: Right, I forgot. It _does_ hold when combined with auto-increment, though, if I'm not mistaken. Then the insert will always get higher IDs than anything that was already read.

Comment: Yes, that's true. If you're using auto-increment with serializable (and the auto-increment is the way you determine order of events), then it will not insert items out of order.